# Kernel pipeline and clEnqueueReadBuffer

Tags: opencl

I have a pipeline of kernels:

1) kernel A writes data into buffer X

2) buffer X is copied to host via clEnqueueReadBuffer

3) host data is processed, in callback triggered by clEnqueueReadBuffer

repeat above

Buffer X is created with the following flags :

```
 CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR | CL_MEM_READ_WRITE; | CL_MEM_HOST_READ_ONLY
```

My question:  once clEnqueueReadBuffer is complete (I have an event triggered by CL_COMPLETE), is it safe for kernel A to run again without 
overwriting data being processed on the host ?

Or should I process the data on the host before I allow kernel A to run again?

Because I am seeing a bug in my code indicating that it is not safe for kernel A to run until I process the data on the host.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the OpenCL 1.2 specification has to say about buffers created with `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR`:

> If specified, it indicates that the application wants the OpenCL implementation to use memory referenced by host_ptr as the storage bits for the memory object.

The implication of this is that it is not safe to simultaneously access this buffer from both the host and the device (unless both are just reading). If you want the host and device allocations to be distinct, just create your buffer *without* the `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` flag.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. I suppose I should RTFM next time :)

Comment: if I create the buffer with `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR`, do I even need to call `clEnqueueReadBuffer` ?

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You do need to map the buffer at least, or there is no guarantee that data will have been written into memory. It could be cached elsewhere in the system. CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR only really guarantees that the target location of a map is consistent.

Comment: Thanks, @Lee.  I tried removing the call with my AMD card, and everything worked fine. But, since the perf didn't improve ( I think the driver removes the call) I will leave it in to be safe.